# Bring the words into the right order!

Tags: pattern, word-sequence

The following words have a hidden but *very distinguished* property that allows to order them in a very natural way:

> pins up iron sigma eyes another ball face sum monkeys

What is the *very distinguished* property of these words?
What is the resulting ordering?

Comment: Requesting a hint: Are there any more words in the English language that could be added to this list?

Comment: @Mark: If suffixes were allowed, you could go with "Oceans", "o'clock", and "Apollo" for the next three.

Comment: This was a good puzzle. Nice job!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Another Face Sum Eyes Monkeys Sigma Up Ball Iron Pins

The property is that these words can be prefixed with numbers to create expressions:

> One Another (an expression meaning "each other")
>  Two-Face (Harvey Dent, a villain in Batman)
>  ThreeSum (the [3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) problem)
>  Four-Eyes (an insulting term for somebody who wears glasses)
>  Five Monkeys (little ones, [jumping on the bed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Little_Monkeys))
>  [Six Sigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma) (a statistical standard for process consistency)
>  Seven-Up (a drink or a children's party game)
>  Eight Ball (a fortune-telling device, or a billiards game)
>  Nine-Iron (a type of golf club)
>  Ten Pins (in bowling)

Comment: My only issue with this is your answers for "ball" and "iron". Not sure how to say this without giving it away for someone not looking at spoilers, but there are a lot of other "irons" that have different categorization. Similarly for "ball" in one of your contexts (but not the other).

Comment: They're the numbers most commonly associated with those words, though, so I went with it.

Comment: I totally get it. I guess it's not an issue with your answer specifically - the answer totally makes sense. It's just that if it's the answer, I think the "iron" one specifically isn't specific enough. I agree with you, though, it's a good puzzle.

Comment: The iron one may not be specific enough, but it *is* the only one left after all the other answers are placed.

Answer (score 6):

The following is just a minor comment on the solution of **Joe Z**.

> Counting does not necessarily start at one, but may also start at zero 
>  (for instance, Ernst Zermelo used this variant).
>  This then allows the following side solution (the differences to Joe Z's solution are shown in boldface):
>
>  **Zero-sum** (a special type of game in game theory)
>  One another (each other; copied from Joe Z.)
>  Two-face (Harvey Dent, a villain in Batman; copied from Joe Z.)
>  **Three monkeys** (the three wise monkeys)
>  Four-Eyes (an insulting term for somebody who wears glasses; copied from Joe Z.)
>  **Five Iron** (golf club that has a relatively narrow metal head)
>  Six Sigma (a statistical standard for process consistency; copied from Joe Z.)
>  Seven-Up (a drink or a children's party game; copied from Joe Z.)
>  Eight Ball (a billiards game; copied from Joe Z.)
>  **Nine-pins** (European bowling game)

Comment: Nice job shifting them over.